# Resource Freeing in Redis Jobs

Tags: redis, jobs

I've an application that sends redid jobs output to front-end via socket. There are some special type nodes those are special & needs to wait to finish their jobs.So I'm using infinite waiting to finish those jobs to complete. Something like below.

```
While True:
  If job.status() == "finished" :
     Break
```

I want to if there's any way to free the resource & re run the jobs from their previous state.

Tried a solution to stay awake all the time. I want a solution where the resources are not bound to one jobs , the system can utilize their resources to other jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you can do is,
To return if the job is special. And save the states of jobs in Redis Environment.
If u have a back end in your application, you can always check if the special jobs are finished running.